# undo function on android canvas

Tags: android, canvas, undo

There are few other questions,similar to mine, that I have followed and  implemented their answers in every possible manner but that doesnt seem to work on my code. I'm close to the solution but seem to be missing on something. Kindly help and I request not to mark the question as duplicate.

here's the mainActivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener                {

 //  private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
//  private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();

private Button btnUndo;

public DrawingView drawView;

//buttons
private ImageButton currPaint, drawBtn, eraseBtn, newBtn, saveBtn, opacityBtn;


//sizes
private float smallBrush, mediumBrush, largeBrush;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawView = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawing);

    //get the palette and first color button
    LinearLayout paintLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.paint_colors);
    currPaint = (ImageButton) paintLayout.getChildAt(0);
    currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));

    //sizes from dimensions
    smallBrush = 10;
    mediumBrush = 20;
    largeBrush = 30;

    //draw button
    drawBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.draw_btn);
    drawBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //set initial size
    drawView.setBrushSize(mediumBrush);

    //erase button
    eraseBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.erase_btn);
    eraseBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //new button
    newBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.new_btn);
    newBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //save button
    saveBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //opacity
    opacityBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.opacity_btn);
    opacityBtn.setOnClickListener(this);



  btnUndo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUndo);
   btnUndo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           drawView.undo();
       }
   });
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

//user clicked paint
public void paintClicked(View view) {
    //use chosen color
    //set erase false
    drawView.setErase(false);
    drawView.setPaintAlpha(100);
    drawView.setBrushSize(drawView.getLastBrushSize());

    if (view != currPaint) {
        ImageButton imgView = (ImageButton) view;
        String color = view.getTag().toString();
        drawView.setColor(color);
        //update ui
        imgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));
        currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint));
        currPaint = (ImageButton) view;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view.getId() == R.id.draw_btn) {
        //draw button clicked
        final Dialog brushDialog = new Dialog(this);
        brushDialog.setTitle("Brush size:");
        brushDialog.setContentView(R.layout.brush_chooser);
        //listen for clicks on size buttons
        ImageButton smallBtn = (ImageButton) brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.small_brush);
        smallBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              drawView.setErase(false);
                drawView.setBrushSize(smallBrush);
                drawView.setLastBrushSize(smallBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ImageButton mediumBtn = (ImageButton) brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.medium_brush);
        mediumBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               drawView.setErase(false);
                drawView.setBrushSize(mediumBrush);
                drawView.setLastBrushSize(mediumBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ImageButton largeBtn = (ImageButton) brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.large_brush);
        largeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(false);
                drawView.setBrushSize(largeBrush);
                drawView.setLastBrushSize(largeBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        //show and wait for user interaction
        brushDialog.show();

    }


    else if (view.getId() == R.id.erase_btn) {
        //switch to erase - choose size
        final Dialog brushDialog = new Dialog(this);
        brushDialog.setTitle("Eraser size:");
        brushDialog.setContentView(R.layout.brush_chooser);
        //size buttons
        ImageButton smallBtn = (ImageButton) brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.small_brush);
        smallBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(true);
                drawView.setBrushSize(smallBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ImageButton mediumBtn = (ImageButton) brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.medium_brush);
        mediumBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(true);
                drawView.setBrushSize(mediumBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ImageButton largeBtn = (ImageButton) brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.large_brush);
        largeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawView.setErase(true);
                drawView.setBrushSize(largeBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        brushDialog.show();
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.new_btn) {
        //new button
        AlertDialog.Builder newDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        newDialog.setTitle("New drawing");
        newDialog.setMessage("Start new drawing (you will lose the current drawing)?");
        newDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                drawView.startNew();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        newDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        newDialog.show();
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.save_btn) {
        //save drawing
        AlertDialog.Builder saveDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        saveDialog.setTitle("Save drawing");
        saveDialog.setMessage("Save drawing to device Gallery?");
        saveDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //save drawing
                drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                //attempt to save
                String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        getContentResolver(), drawView.getDrawingCache(),
                        UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png", "drawing");
                //feedback
                if (imgSaved != null) {
                    Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Drawing saved to Gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    savedToast.show();
                } else {
                    Toast unsavedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Oops! Image could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    unsavedToast.show();
                }
                drawView.destroyDrawingCache();
            }
        });
        saveDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        saveDialog.show();
    }

 /*  else if (view.getId() == R.id.btnUndo) {
        //undo drawing
        {
            //drawView.setErase(true);
            drawView.undo();

           /* if (paths.size() > 0) {
               // drawView.setErase(true);
                undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
                view.invalidate();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "undo isnt working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/


           else if (view.getId() == R.id.opacity_btn) {
               //launch opacity chooser
               final Dialog seekDialog = new Dialog(this);
               seekDialog.setTitle("Opacity level:");
               seekDialog.setContentView(R.layout.opacity_chooser);
               //get ui elements
               final TextView seekTxt = (TextView) seekDialog.findViewById(R.id.opq_txt);
               final SeekBar seekOpq = (SeekBar) seekDialog.findViewById(R.id.opacity_seek);
               //set max
               seekOpq.setMax(100);
               //show current level
               int currLevel = drawView.getPaintAlpha();
               seekTxt.setText(currLevel + "%");
               seekOpq.setProgress(currLevel);
               //update as user interacts
               seekOpq.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                       seekTxt.setText(Integer.toString(progress) + "%");
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                   }

               });
               //listen for clicks on ok
               Button opqBtn = (Button) seekDialog.findViewById(R.id.opq_ok);
               opqBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       drawView.setPaintAlpha(seekOpq.getProgress());
                       seekDialog.dismiss();
                   }
               });
               //show dialog
               seekDialog.show();
           }
       }
   }
```

DrawingView.java:

(Undo function is at the bottom of this class)

```
public class DrawingView extends View{

private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();

private Path drawPath;
//drawing and canvas paint
private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
//initial color
private int paintColor = 0xFF660000, paintAlpha = 255;
//canvas
private Canvas drawCanvas;
//canvas bitmap
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
//brush sizes
private float brushSize, lastBrushSize;
//erase flag
private boolean erase = false;




public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setupDrawing();


}

private void setupDrawing() {

    brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
    lastBrushSize = brushSize;
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
   // paths.add(drawPath);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

//draw the view - will be called after touch event
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (Path path : paths) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, drawPaint);
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);

    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}

//register user touches as drawing action
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();
    //respond to down, move and up events
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    //redraw
    invalidate();
    return true;

}

//update color
public void setColor(String newColor) {
    invalidate();
    //check whether color value or pattern name
    if (newColor.startsWith("#")) {
        paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setShader(null);
    } else {
        //pattern
        int patternID = getResources().getIdentifier(
                newColor, "drawable", "com.example.drawingfun");
        //decode
        Bitmap patternBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), patternID);
        //create shader
        BitmapShader patternBMPshader = new BitmapShader(patternBMP,
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        //color and shader
        drawPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        drawPaint.setShader(patternBMPshader);
    }
}

//set brush size
public void setBrushSize(float newSize) {
    float pixelAmount = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            newSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    brushSize = pixelAmount;
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
}

//get and set last brush size
public void setLastBrushSize(float lastSize) {
    lastBrushSize = lastSize;
}

public float getLastBrushSize() {
    return lastBrushSize;
}

//set erase true or false
public void setErase(boolean isErase) {
    erase = isErase;
    if (erase) drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    else drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
}

//start new drawing
public void startNew() {
    drawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    invalidate();
}

//return current alpha
public int getPaintAlpha() {
    return Math.round((float) paintAlpha / 255 * 100);
}

//set alpha
public void setPaintAlpha(int newAlpha) {
    paintAlpha = Math.round((float) newAlpha / 100 * 255);
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAlpha(paintAlpha);
}

//define undo func
public void undo() {
    if (paths.size() > 0) {
        undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
        invalidate();
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "undo isnt working wth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: prolly because you didn't do something obvious like creating new path in  and put it into array "on down" ... in "on draw" you should obviously draw all paths from this array

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with this earlier today, This is a fairly old ticket so I am not sure if you are interested still... however someone else might be.

I think the issue is that you only ever use one instance of path - its kinda odd but the path isn't just point A-B

I think what you need to do is to make new paths prior to putting them into your collection - Selvin said this in his comment.

For example you could do something like this;

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
float touchX = event.getX();
float touchY = event.getY();
//respond to down, move and up events
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //Make a new instance of DrawPath
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        drawPath.reset();
        break;
    default:
        return false;
}
//redraw
invalidate();
return true;
```

}

when you do path rest I suspect it is clearing all the lines that are drawn - this is because they are all one path (despite the fact several on-touch events have made them).

if this doesnt work let me know what actually is the problem - is the line not appearing etc...